# How do you install and share Bootstrap from Angular Shared Lib

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, bootstrap-5, monorepo

I am creating multiple application (projects) in an Angular workspace, following this approach in Angular Documentation (https://angular.io/guide/file-structure). This is the monorepo multiple application approach.

[image]

Now, I want to install Bootstrap, but ONLY in my-lib (shared lib) and expose it to all other projects. I don't want to have Bootstrap installed in every single project. I heard that you can do this, but not sure how it can be done.
So, my question is, how can I install Bootstrap only in lib and share it to other application inside the same angular workspace?

Comment: angular workspaces require you to rebuild projects on each change before you can use the updated version in other projects. Try to use [NX](https://nx.dev/getting-started/intro) instead (or another monorepo tool like [Lerna](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-monorepo-lerna/), ...). [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap) a good, advanced ng-bootstrap library you can use

Comment: NX is good. I am using that too for a monorepo. What is the best practice to have ng-bootstrap available in all applications in workspace? do you have to add it in every single one?

Comment: Afaik for nx workspaces apps don't seem to have a package.json and solely rely on the package.json in to root of the workspace